# Queue not working on anaconda/binstar?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, binstar

I use the `conda-build` system to build some python packages I maintain.  I build them on my Mac, and then upload them to [anaconda.org / binstar.org](https://anaconda.org/moble/), so that people can access them through the usual `conda` method.  This all works fine.

But I've also set up anaconda.org to automatically build the linux versions.  They should build automatically every time I push a change to the github repos, but I can also manually trigger a build from the website, or via the command-line interface.  This also *used to* work flawlessly.  However, for the past day or so, every time a build has triggered in any of those ways, it has immediately failed with logs like the following:

```
Build 32.1 Sumitted id:55c62fde59da984cebfd25f8
There are *NO* healthy workers accepting jobs for the queue build/binstar/public. Your build was not submitted
```

I also notice that many of the times listed on the build pages are just plain wrong.  Don't know if that's related...

Google is only finding a few (old) instances of this error, for projects that have since built correctly.  And questions about this on [the github page](https://github.com/Anaconda-Server/docs.anaconda.org/issues/76) and [the conda mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/d/topic/conda/-mgyooHpvCA/discussion) haven't attracted any interest.

Is this the wrong queue?  If so how do I change it?  Have I run over some quota by starting too many builds?  Is this service no longer available?  Or just temporarily unavailable?  Can I solve this in any way?  Is there some better place to ask this question?

Answer (score 0):

[Apparently](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/d/msg/conda/-mgyooHpvCA/n6H2NzADDQAJ), the workers were simply taken down for maintenance, and not brought up until Monday morning.  I'm a little surprised there wasn't a more informative message about this, and very surprised that google didn't turn up anyone else with this issue.